# AWS Credentials from Nuget package in C#

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, nuget, amazon-kinesis

I'm building a Nuget package that will be able to Put data into a Kinesis Steam on AWS.

I do not want the Nuget package itself to contain any credentials. I want the nuget package to use the keys in the web.config or app.config of whatever application is using it.

My question is:

Will this happen by default?
Or will the AmazonKinesisClient try to read from the app.config of the nuget package itself and then give up?

In the latter case, is there any way for the nuget package to load the credentials from the hosting application, or will the hosting application be forced to explicitly pass credentials to the nuget package?

I'd very much prefer to not force the hosting application to pass credentials.

The nuget package is targeting .NET Framework V4.5

Comment: You can create Config class and add different methods of filling it. For example ReadFromFile(string filePath).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you are using the AWS SDK inside a Nuget package, it will still get connection information from the app.config of the running application.

I have tested this and confirmed this by building a console app in .net 4.5, adding profile information to the app config. Then creating a separate library and packaging it using nuget. This library supplies no credentials. I added the Nuget package to my console application and it successfully connected to the account profile specified in the app.config.

If an application is creating a Kinesis client using the AWS dotnet SDK and your package isn't specifically passing credentials to the client, then the SDK looks for the credentials in the order listed below.

I would provide developers with an option of supplying credentials to your class too so that they can manually set the credential.  Developers may have another mechanism for managing credentials than the profiles system that the SDK uses.

The SDK will:

- Look for AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretKey in App.config
- Search the SDK
- Store Search the credentials file
- Search for Instance Profiles

More Information can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/referencing-credentials-using-profiles/

Comment: Right, but that's not quite what I was asking. My question was whether or not the AWS sdk will look at the app.config in the nuget package or in the hosting application. I haven't been able to find documentation on this

Comment: I have edited the answer to more clearly answer the original question. In short. The running app that is consuming the nuget library's app.config will be used.